# secure socket connection (wss) with java and webgl

Tags: java, c#

I had successfully tried ws communication using WebGL.

Here is my front end code written in c#.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;

public class EchoExample : MonoBehaviour {

    UnityWebSocket WebSocket;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        // This example service echoes back any messages sent to it
        WebSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketServerExample/websocketendpoint");
        WebSocket.OnClose += WebSocket_OnClose;
        WebSocket.OnOpen += Websocket_OnOpen;
        WebSocket.OnMessage += WebSocket_OnMessage;
        WebSocket.OnError += WebSocket_OnError;
    }

    private void WebSocket_OnClose(UnityWebSocket sender, int code, string reason) {

        Debug.Log("Connection closed: " + reason);
    }

    private void Websocket_OnOpen(UnityWebSocket accepted) {

        Debug.Log("Connection established.");

        string message = "Hello, friend!";

        Debug.Log("Sending message: " + message);

        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

        WebSocket.SendAsync(data);
    }

    private void WebSocket_OnMessage(UnityWebSocket sender, byte[] data) {

        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

        Debug.Log("Message received: " + message);
    }

    private void WebSocket_OnError(UnityWebSocket sender, string message) {
        Debug.Log("Error: " + message);
    }
}
```

here is my java code.

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocketendpoint")
public class WsServer {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        System.out.println("Open Connection ...");
         try {
             session.getBasicRemote().sendText("$ Kimaya Server 2003 $");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
        System.out.println("Session " + session.getId() + " has ended");
    }

/*  @OnMessage
        public String onMessage(String s, Session session){
            System.out.println("Message from the client: " +s);
            return s;
         }
*/
    @OnMessage
    public void processUpload(byte[] bytes, boolean last, Session session) throws IOException {

        String s = new String(bytes);

        //  public String onMessage(String message, Session session){

//      byte in[] = message.getBytes();

            System.out.println("Message from the client: " +s);
            String welcomeString = "this is response from server";
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(welcomeString);
            //      onMessage("from server", session);


    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I had successfully done communication using ws but now next step is I want to do it with wss i.e. via secure connection, after do lot of searching still I am not able to get any example or documentation related to this does anybody tried it before ??

Comment: What type of secure connection do you want to use?  http uses tcp as transport layer  so most solutions do the encryption in tcp layer.

Comment: I need https connection, I used websocket connection for communication but I don't know whether wss internally uses tcp or not.

Comment: See wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket  Webpage says folllowing : "WebSocket is a different TCP protocol from HTTP" which means that different TCP Port numbers are used but it is still TCP.

Comment: Yes I got your point !! now I am trying to do it using encryption technique over tcp layer , any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: I always seem to get back to the same codeproject.  It is very old, but it has been updated recently : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2642/SSL-TLS-client-server-for-NET-and-SSL-tunnelling

Comment: Thank you @jdweng.